# Refactoring big database views

Tags: sql, oracle, refactoring, view

I am an intern (which means I have no decision power, I know sql and pl/sql)  and got the Task to refactor some huge database views

Basically the problem is that all views relay on big view which is querying all data and the other views filter further (thoes views all query data for letters and emails) these views are Not documented so I need to find out what they do and rebuild them so that there won't be a query that acquires all that from the database.

My problem is that those views (btw each about 600 lines) are written very wiredly (as far as I know written by a non programmer) and I have no idea where to start, what is the first thing todo? What would you suggest?

Comment: When you say you are an intern, does that mean you have no experience in  Oracle or SQL generally?

Comment: Ask the person who uses the view what he/she actually like to see. Based on this requirements start from scratch.

Comment: may be you can start with `create view view_name` ;)

Comment: I am trained in sql and pl/sql I just wanted to point out that I have no say here, I just need to do this... The person who uses this just pushes a button and the letters will be built, printed and shipped automatically.. These views hand over the necessary information to the software which is actually building the letters

Comment: "Refactoring" is not a matter of just following a recipe. You need a specific goal - e.g. to make the code more readable, easier to maintain, improve encapsulation, or whatever. Without a goal, you won't know when you're "done".

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those "stick your finger in the air" kind of questions; it's almost impossible to say what you should do, as it depends entirely on the sql used to create the views, the data in the tables, the structure of the tables etc, etc.

My suggestion would be to start with the base view and see what basic things you can do to aid peformance - for example, can you make use of sub-query factoring? can you change things to filter early? Can things be replaced by an analytic query?

Break things down, too. If you have a subquery in the original view that you think can be optimised, well, it's easy to compare the results of two different sql statements - if they match, it's generally a good indication that you've rewritten the statement correctly (not always, though, so be careful! Test thoroughly!)

Breaking a complex query down to its constituent parts should also allow you to work out what it's trying to do a lot easier!